# Navigating Navigation Bar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

So I'm working on project with flutter. First I want to know if using a bottom Navigation Bar is better than creating a container for it. Now my question, how do I navigate to a page by using this bottom Navigation bar? Like should I build an entire page and bottom navigation bar for each one? OR Can I build everything in one place ?

This a part of it

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<ProfilePage> createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}

class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('HOME'),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.green[900],
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
        ),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [],
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.green[900],
          items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.home,
              ),
              label: 'Home',
              backgroundColor: Colors.green[900],
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.calendar_today,
              ),
              label: 'Days',
              backgroundColor: Colors.green[900],
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.local_activity,
              ),
              label: 'Activity',
              backgroundColor: Colors.green[900],
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.settings,
              ),
              label: 'Settings',
              backgroundColor: Colors.green[900],
            ),
          ],
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
          onTap: _onItemTapped,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is how it looks but don't know how to navigate between screens.

[image]

Comment: I want to know the code to navigate between these four without creating more screens.

Answer (score 1):

you PageView class for change pages

Change Column to Pageview

```
final PageController controller = PageController();
return PageView(
  /// [PageView.scrollDirection] defaults to [Axis.horizontal].
  /// Use [Axis.vertical] to scroll vertically.`enter code here`
  controller: controller,
  children: const <Widget>[
    Center(
      child: Text('First Page'),
    ),
    Center(
      child: Text('Second Page'),
    ),
    Center(
      child: Text('Third Page'),
    )
  ],
);
```

}

change in your method

```
 void _onItemTapped(int index) {
setState(() {
  _selectedIndex = index;
  controller.jumpToPage(index);
});
```

}

Comment: where should i add this

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a BnB for each screen, you can create a navbar on the main screen

and in the build method return the corresponding page, based on the selected index.

Comment: Consider adding example code